# I deployed flask on hosting iis on my company server the.. i made the configuration work but i had problem in post request

Tags: python, image-processing, iis, flask

i need to send photo by postman to this flask api in order to make ocr on it but always got errors when i send post request, when i send get request it works well

```
import pytesseract   
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect , url_for ,render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from cv2 import cv2 
import re

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ocr"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
app.secret_key = b'_5#y5L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

@app.route('/bar',methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def bar(): 
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            # check if the post request has the file part 
            if 'file' not in request.files:  
                flash('No file part') 
                return ('nothing')#redirect(request.url) 
            file = request.files.get('file') 
            #file = request.files.get['file'] 
            # if user does not select file, browser also 
            # submit an empty part without filename 
            if file.filename == '': 
                flash('No selected file') 
                return ('no file name') 
            elif file and allowed_file(file.filename): 
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename) 
                filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename) 
                file.save(filepath) 
                img = io.imread(filepath, as_gray = True)
                #img = cv2.imread(filepath) 
                result = ocr(img) 
                #file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) 
                #filepath = (os.path.join(app.config['imgdir'], filename)) 
                return (result) 
                #return ('okkkk') 
return ('hello') 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=9010)
```

always return 'nothing' even if i sent photo by postman and when i remove if 'file' not in

```
request.files:
flash('No file part')
return 'nothing'
```

i get error on postman (500 internal server error ) i think the problem is the file(photo) not 
received from postman to flask or maybe its not accepting the photo? any one have solution.. thanks 
and this the web.config :

```
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
        <add name="FlaskHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ocr\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    <add name="Python FastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ocr\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
   </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
 </system.webServer>
 <appSettings>
   <!-- Required settings -->
   <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
   <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ocr" />
 </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: i have to mention that its working well on the development server with anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when sending a file from the postman but I was sending file and JSON data together, but I started using `form-data` in postman with which I send the file to the server via `POST` and some extra data in JSON that I need.

Then in my flask app endpoint, I'm reading it like this:

`request.files["file_name"]`

Also, you should use `secure_filename` from `werkzeug` to make file secure, e.g. `from werkzeug import secure_filename`

P.s. make sure that when you call this code:

```py
if 'file' not in request.files:  
    flash('No file part') 
    return ('nothing')  # redirect(request.url)
```

That you have named your file in request `file` if not, then you can't find it by this key in the dictionary of `request` as it doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you.. do you know how can i be sure what is my file name in request ? because i can't find it in postman

Comment: because statement 'if request.files' giving true that mean the file is received but when i write file = request.files['file'] gives error that mean i received it but i can't access

Comment: You could debug it by writing `print(request.files)` in yor code and this should print the content of `files` and you should see the name of a file that you are receiving.

Comment: thank you.. your answers helped me a lot and now my api working well on server